# VS Code update will not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

## Problem

`VS Code` correctly announces `1.24.1` is available for update.

I click button to install and after short wait receive prompt to restart Visual Studio Code and complete the install.

After restart the update has not been applied and again get announcement:

> the version `1.24.1` is available for update.

---

### Question

Is this fixable, or should I give up and download the latest version for re-install?

### Information additional

- System : `Windows 7 Pro`.
- VS Code version: `Version 1.23.1`
- Architecture x64

Answer (score 2):

Try running the program as administrator before updating.

Comment: It is assumed that if it is helpful you will be given a positive point